# Does the jar library built from Kotlin code still have all the feature like accessing local Kotlin code

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am looking at this https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_libraries.html

to build a Kotlin jar library. But I am wondering -- if consumer code of the library is also using Kotlin, can it have all the benefits like accessing to local Kotlin code? For example:

1. Nullability check
2. Suspend keyword restriction
3. Named parameters
4. ...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer is YES as long as the jar is built with source files.

Answer (score 0):

#### `suspend`

The `suspend` keyword changes the descriptor of the functions to have an interface, `Continuation<ReturnType>` at the end of the parameter list. So if you have
`suspend fun foo(i: Int, l: Long): String` in kotlin, it gets compiled and decompiled to Java:
`public final Object foo(int i, long l, Continuation<? super String> $completion)`. This is why some libraries had Java friendly functions that wraps suspend function call in `runBlocking`.

#### Null Checks

This works across languages, when kotlin compiles a function or expression call that specifies a non-null value, it adds null checks to the code. For example:
`fun bar(s1: String, s2: String)` adds these check in the method body:

```kotlin
Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object)s1, "s1");
Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object)s2, "s2");
```

And throws an exception when it is null.

Comment: Actually my original question is about kotlin code(not Java) using kotlin library. But thanks for your insightful explanation!